How can I expand the background of the BottomSheetDialog
I'm facing an issue with the Bottom sheet dialog. I trying to get have the Background sort of Growing with the dragging of the dialog but unfortunately its not doing so. I tried to set some styles but its not working for me. Maybe do I have to do something with the onSlide?
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(),
    R.style.Base_ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_BottomSheetDialog)
    bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
        val d = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheet = d.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet) 
        as FrameLayout
        bottomSheet.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_sheet_background)
        d.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
        val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
        behavior.isFitToContents = false
        behavior.halfExpandedRatio = 0.5f
        behavior.peekHeight = BottomSheetBehavior.PEEK_HEIGHT_AUTO
        behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                // Handle the slide offset if needed
            }
        })
    }
    return bottomSheetDialog
}

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/waypoint_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Waypoint Information"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/waypoint_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Perform Action"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="100dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

I tried to set some the style xml with a transparent background but it wasn´t successful.
here are the resources:
<resources>
    <style name="Base_ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_BottomSheetDialog"
    parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
        <!-- Customize your theme here if needed -->
    </style>
</resources>

I also created another background drawable:
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp" android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

I was expecting that when you drag the dialog to the center or the top that the background is sort of growing with it.

Additionally here are some screenshots of the dialog:
Dialog view not dragged
Dialog view dragged to the top
Dialog view dragged to the center
